# Add ellipsis for overflow text in selected option Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Like in the title, I am trying to add ellipsis to selected option in `select` if string which represent selected value is to long. Is there any way to do this with pipe or other trick to manipulate display of selected value. I was trying to use css

```
       text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

but it's not work on Chrome.

Comment: you want an ellipsis on the options, or on the select ?

Comment: On the slecet. Options should display normaly but if I select some of them and for example lenght of that option is 10 i want to add ellipsis at the end on of that option and slice it to 5.